Regarding Solar Trajectory in AR-3D for iOS
I am bit new to AR concepts and I want to show Solar trajectory in my app using AR 3D model , I have tried some approach but it didn't work for me, any third party library reference or any help will be appreciated.
Thank you so much
I tried SCNGeometry to draw solar line , line appears but it is very thin line , I want to make line thick and continuous
